# Did Maureen Healy, who was shot in the head by Feds in Portland, write the following press release?

Tags: united-states, social-media

There is a "press release" circulating on the internet. It purports to have been written by Maureen Healy, the protestor who received a [blow to the head from a projectile](https://amarketnews.com/2020/07/26/portland-protests-update-professor-maureen-healy-shot-in-the-head-by-fed-agents/) in Portland, Oregon. This morning on Facebook, a friend posted the image below.

https://pamplinmedia.com/pt/9-news/474921-383910-lewis-and-clark-history-department-chair-shot-at-protest
[image]

The same statement has also been [posted by Feminist News on facebook](https://www.facebook.com/feministnews.us/posts/1262337714113444), with thousands of shares and comments.

My question: is this statement authentic?

Comment: All previous comments deleted as obsolete.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's authentic. Lewis and Clark College posted [Sharing Professor Healy’s Protest Story with Congress](https://www.lclark.edu/live/news/43975-sharing-professor-healys-protest-story-with) on their website, which links to [a letter from the college's president, Wim Wiewel](https://www.lclark.edu/live/files/30218-wiewelletter-torepresentativespdf), and includes the same statement from the professor at the end of the letter.

---

[Here is another link to that letter](https://www.lclark.edu/live/files/30218-president-wiewels-letter-to-representatives).